# Hibernate Criteria for different field value length

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I've got an Entity which have a (string) field of size = 10

```
@Column(length = 10)
String code;
```

However, field's value length could be 5 or 10. I would like to create a hibernate criteria matching that field's value according to its length, like:

```
final List<String> codesLong= new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> codesShort= new ArrayList<String>();
...
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.in("code", codesShort),
Restrictions.eq("code.length", 5)),
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.in("code", codesLong),
Restrictions.eq("code.length", 10)))
);
```

However... the above looks nice but, obviously, won't work. I do not know how to deal with that problem. 
I would be grateful for any hints.

thanks

// solution (thanks Stanislav!) 
Entity:

```
@Column(length = 10)
String code;

@Formula(" length(code) ")
int codelength; // create GETter method as well
```

Criteria:

```
final List<String> codesLong= new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> codesShort= new ArrayList<String>();
...
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.in("code", codesShort),
Restrictions.eq("codelength", 5)),
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.in("code", codesLong),
Restrictions.eq("codelength", 10)))
);
```

Comment: code.length refers to no:of characters in string or something else.

Comment: Code is a simple string "String code;" . "length" is there just to visualize what I would like to archieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce an artificial Entity field codeLength and use @Formula annotation (example [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation))

and use the codeLength in the criteria.