# How to create query using length(string) in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm looking to create this query in Hibernate:

```
SELECT * FROM `entity` WHERE length(word) > 2 and length(word) < 6;
```

I tried this, but failed.

```
- List<Criterion> criterions = new ArrayList<>();
- criterions.add(Restrictions.sizeGt("word", 2));
- criterions.add(Restrictions.sizeGt("word", 6));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria for different field value length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235541/hibernate-criteria-for-different-field-value-length)

Answer (score 0):

How is this question 5 years old with 1k views and no correct answers?

The code example that original poster provided is incorrect.

To have value length restriction `length(word) < 6` you have to use **sizeLt**:

```
List<Criterion> criterions = new ArrayList<>();
criterions.add(Restrictions.sizeGt("word", 2));
criterions.add(Restrictions.sizeLt("word", 6));
```

Answer (score -4):

The simplest possible Hibernate query is of the form:

```
from eg.Cat
```

This returns all instances of the class `eg.Cat`. You do not usually need to qualify the class name, since auto-import is the default. 
For example:

```
from Cat
```

In order to refer to the Cat in other parts of the query, you will need to assign an alias. 
For example:

```
from Cat as cat
```

This query assigns the alias cat to Cat instances, so you can use that alias later in the query. The as keyword is optional. You could also write:

```
from Cat cat
```

Multiple classes can appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter

from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

It is good practice to name query aliases using an initial lowercase as this is consistent with Java naming standards for local variables (e.g. domesticCat).

Comment: can you give me example code from this query use hibernate Criterion?
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE length(word) > 2 and length(word) < 6;

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to explain how to make a criteria based on a string's length